# Element Mandatory declaration in XSD Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to know how to make the below fields as mandatory and optional field in xsd declaration.

In the AccDetailsRequest i want **USERNAME** and **EMAIL** as mandatory field and **PHONE** as optional field.

```
<xsd:element name="AccDetailsRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="USERNAME" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="EMAIL" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="PHONE" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:element>
```

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`. their default values are 1.
try the following:

```
<xsd:element name="AccDetailsRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="USERNAME" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="EMAIL" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="PHONE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:element>
```